# Controlling PointSize in a RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, version-10, geometry, style

I have a "named" point in Mathematica 10 and am plotting it like this using RegionPlot:

```
  $PointStyle = Directive@{PointSize[1], Red};
distanceX = Sqrt[(x - 8000)^2 + y^2];
distanceY = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
rate1 = 45;
rate2 = 60;
point["camp location"] = Point[{8000, 0}];
curve["Circle of Apollonius"] = 
  ImplicitRegion[distanceX/distanceY == rate1/rate2, {x, y}];
Show[
 RegionPlot[{curve["Circle of Apollonius"], point["camp location"]}, 
  Method -> {"DiscretizationMethod" -> "Symbolic"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 40000}, {-20000, 20000}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {$PointStyle}]]
```

[image: Curve of Apollonius]

As can be seen in the output the dot is kind of small. Unfortunately, the plot is not using my attempt to change the PointSize directive and plots the point as a small period-sized dot no matter what. How can I change the size of the dot?

I tried using a separate ListPlot inside of the Show, but in this case no dot appears at all:

```
    $PointStyle = Directive@{PointSize[Large], Red};
Show[{
   RegionPlot[{ curve["path to camp"] }, Method -> {"DiscretizationMethod" -> "Symbolic"}],
   ListPlot[{ point["camp location"]},  PlotStyle -> {$PointStyle}]}]
```

Comment: Plot the point with `ListPlot` and use `Show` to combine it with the `RegionPlot`.

Comment: @paw I tried this (code above) but the dot disappeared completely.

Comment: Please post a full working example.

Comment: @paw I have posted a full text example.

Comment: Use option `BoundaryStyle -> Directive@{PointSize[Large], Red}`

Comment: Or you can use `Epilog`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to separate the `RegionPlot` from the point you are trying to plot, and instead render it separately:

```
distanceX = Sqrt[(x - 8000)^2 + y^2];
distanceY = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
rate1 = 45;
rate2 = 60;
point["camp location"] = Point[{8000, 0}];
curve["Circle of Apollonius"] = 
  ImplicitRegion[distanceX/distanceY == rate1/rate2, {x, y}];
Show[RegionPlot[{curve["Circle of Apollonius"]}, 
  Method -> {"DiscretizationMethod" -> "Symbolic"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 40000}, {-20000, 20000}}], 
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, point["camp location"]}]]
```

which produces

[image]

Points can always be plotted separately by rendering them with `Graphics[{BunchOfDirectives, Point[...]}]`, so that you don't need to worry about figuring out how to tell `RegionPlot` that you want one particular point to have a certain set of directives.

By the way, if you use `PointSize[1]` like your original code seems to attempt, instead of `PointSize[Large]`, you get this horror:

[image]

### Additional clarification

Jens pointed out in his comment that there is a fundamental difference in how Mathematica displays `Point` in your original code, and how my version displays it: when you include the `Point` inside `RegionPlot`, Mathematica interprets it as a region object which is to be displayed.

For example, replacing `point["camp location"]` in your original code with `Disk[{20000, 0}, 4000]` generates this:

[image]

It doesn't look very `Disk`-shaped, does it? That's because it's plotting it as a discretized region of a `Disk`, rather than as a `Disk` graphics object.

In contrast, watch what happens when the `Disk` is moved outside of the `RegionPlot` and rendered separately:

```
Show[RegionPlot[{curve["Circle of Apollonius"]}, 
  Method -> {"DiscretizationMethod" -> "Symbolic"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 40000}, {-20000, 20000}}], 
 Graphics[{Red, Disk[{20000, 0}, 4000]}]]
```

[image]

Here `Disk` is rendered as a `Disk` graphics, and actually looks round.

Comment: (+1) Maybe you can include a comment regarding the difference between `Point` in a `RegionPlot` and in `Graphics`: the ability to include `Point` in `RegionPlot` as done in the question is due to the fact that `Point` *can* be interpreted as a "region" just like e.g. a `Disk` can. But in that interpretation (which depends entirely on the context being `RegionPlot`), it's impossible to use styling the way one expects it to work for the `Graphics` primitive `Point`. These are basically two different incarnations of `Point`, and the styling only works when removing it as a `RegionPlot` argument.

Comment: @Jens: Thanks for the info, I didn't know that! I added a couple examples which highlight the difference between the two graphics interpretations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use option `Epilog`

```
$PointStyle = Directive@{PointSize[Large], Red};
distanceX = Sqrt[(x - 8000)^2 + y^2];
distanceY = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
rate1 = 45;
rate2 = 60;
point["camp location"] =
  Point[{8000, 0}];
curve["Circle of Apollonius"] = 
  ImplicitRegion[distanceX/distanceY == rate1/rate2, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[{curve["Circle of Apollonius"]}, 
 Method -> {"DiscretizationMethod" -> "Symbolic"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 40000}, {-20000, 20000}},
 Epilog -> {$PointStyle, point["camp location"]}]
```